# Trying to grab things from Database that the user has not seen

Tags: mysql

I've got multiple databases for grabbing info.  I have one that shows which page the user has viewed as well as a separate user DB.  What I am trying to do is find all the pages the user hasn't seen.  At this point just doing != user_id doesn't work as it just shows the other people who have viewed various pages.

So I need to essentially check all page records to see if user has been there and to return back the ids that the user has not seen.

This is where I'm at at this point:

```
SELECT video_id, ads_general.id, id_inc, user_id
FROM ads_general
LEFT JOIN ads_viewed ON (
ads_viewed.video_id = ads_general.id
)
```

Results:

```
video_id    id  id_inc  user_id
gd27hcsc    gd27hcsc    1   1
k2ku1mkp    k2ku1mkp    2   1
umym9ivq    umym9ivq    3   1
umym9ivq    umym9ivq    3   5
5l66bd0f    5l66bd0f    4   1
5l66bd0f    5l66bd0f    4   4
NULL    vvw54epx    5   NULL
```

This query shows the id for the video and the user that has viewed the page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select any video_ids that the user_id isn't attributed to (hasn't seen)?

You likely need to add DISTINCT to your query, so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT video_id
...
WHERE User_Id != [user_id]
```

This will ensure that each one comes back only once.

Comment: That sounds right.  I'm trying to get deep into MYSQL but I'm much less experienced with it than with PHP.  But I believe that is the idea.  Mainly that I have a list of videos and I'm trying to get the ones that the user HAS NOT seen.  I know I could use WHILE loops and such for random video grab -- but having a correct list of videos to randomly select from is what I'm going for.  Thanks for the suggestion -- I'll try it when I get home